# Hi, need a little help understanding Motorola in assembler

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

If I have:

```
0000 3304    alpha:    dc.w    5,16,4,-2
```

and my instruction is: `sub.w    alpha+2,D0`

Is my alpha at `0000 33004` or is it at `00 05 00 01 00 04 FE`?

Comment: Do you have a good book on the 6800 instruction set family?

Comment: Years back while in college I used an assembler targeting this chipset. I think it made use of the reduced instruction set arch.

Comment: not to be rude but how is this helping? I do have the Instructions manual but htat doesnt help

Answer (score 3):

**dc.w** a = define constant word, where a is the value to define

**sb.w** a,b = subtract word, where a is the source and b is the destination

Instruction

```
0000 3304    alpha:    dc.w    5,16,4,-2
```

is equivalent to:

```
0000 3304    alpha:    dc.w   05
             alpha:    dc.w   16
             alpha:    dc.w   04
             alpha:    dc.w  -02
```

To break up a bit more, the first instruction is saying starting at address **0000 3304**, define a value of **5** then define a value of **16**, then a value of **4** and so on. Since each of these values are instructed as a word, whenever a new value is defined, you must increment the address for that value by hex 2 for two bytes/the length for a word.

After the constants have all been defined, the following values will live at the following addresses

```
0000 3304 ->  0x05
0000 3306 ->  0x10       
0000 3308 ->  0x04
0000 330A ->  0xFE
```

What instruction `sub.w alpha+2,D0` is saying, is to starting at alpha (address `0000 3304`) move 2 bytes and subtract that value at that address from the value in data register `D0`.

so,

`alpha+2` = address `0000 33006`

which has a value of `0x10`.

Whatever value is in data register `D0`, subtract `0x10` from it.

Comment: what do you mean subtract 0x04?

Comment: @HaroldB you will subtract 4 from the value inside data register d0

Comment: `alpha+2` means `alpha` plus 2 _bytes_, unless this is some exotic assembler I haven't heard of.

Comment: @Michael 2 bytes to the address or the value? I thought it was the address, as in incrementing a pointer by 2

Comment: @moncadad: The address. Assemblers generally don't perform scaling in expressions like these, and for good reason (IMO). What if you had declared multiple types of data after `alpha`..? Which of them would you expect `alpha` to "be"? Or what if you had an expression like `alpha+beta`, where `beta` was another label followed by declaration of some other data type (or even code)? You can try this out with the GNU m68k assembler and see for yourself.